# Getting an error in injecting $filter in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use http://jsfiddle.net/phaas/8jFpV/. Getting an error in injecting `$filter`

```
// Converts value parameter from yyyyMMdd into yyyy/MM/dd format and vice versa
app.directive('DateConverter', function($compile, $filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

            function fromUser(text) {
                var value = $filter('date')(text, "yyyyMMdd");
                return value;
            }

            function toUser(text) {
                var value = $filter('date')(text, "short");
                return value;               
            }

            ngModel.$parsers.push(fromUser);
            ngModel.$formatters.push(toUser);
        }
    };
});
```

> angular.js:4387 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>       at angular.js:38
>       at angular.js:4387
>       at m (angular.js:336)
>       at g (angular.js:4348)
>       at eb (angular.js:4274)
>       at d (angular.js:1630)
>       at Ac (angular.js:1651)
>       at Zd (angular.js:1545)
>       at angular.js:28361
>       at HTMLDocument.a (angular.js:2998)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name **DateConverter** to **dateConverter**
the naming is incorrect it need to be in camelCase.

Comment: The link you provide you dont using the directive you posted. here. also the question is about $injector error, and it become because naming the directive incorrectly, if you want to  use those directive. plz. provide. an example with your attemp.